# std::max_element for float array

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a function which returns a float * like and another which returns the length of that array:

```
float *getTestData() {
    static float tdata[] = {1.0, 5.0, 10};
    return tdata; 
}

unsigned int getTestDataLen() {
    return 3;
}
```

Now i want to find the max element with std::max_element. Is there any way to get an iterator from that array with the known length at runtime but not at compile time? I can use anything up to C++17. The return of getTestData is just a sample. The plan is to return any length.

Comment: `std::max_element(tdata, tdata + 3)`

Comment: Why a C-style array and all the pointer and size nonsense? Why not just use/return a `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: Are you allowed to change these archaic  functions or are they set in stone?

Comment: The point is that these pointer come from a base class which has multiple implementations which may contain quite large datasets and there is no guarantee that the implementation contains a vector but a memory mapped file instead. I like vectors and use them a lot but this was a design decision wich gave us more flexibility on the implementation side.

Comment: @Gustavo "there is no guarantee that the implementation contains a vector but a memory mapped file instead" If you don't know what you are getting back, how's the caller ever supposed to handle it correctly?

Comment: @JesperJuhl The caller doesn't need to know because he knows the first address and the length. Thats is the idea behind using pointers in this case. The implementation can be anything. It doesn't matter if it is a vector where one can return data() or a mapped file. The only requirement is continous memory.

Answer (score 2):

You could just treat the `float*` as an iterator if you're stuck with this design descision.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

float *getTestData() {
    static float tdata[] = {1.0, 5.0, 10};
    return tdata; 
}

unsigned int getTestDataLen() {
    return 3;
}

int main() {    
    auto begin = getTestData();
    auto end = std::next(begin, getTestDataLen());

    auto maxit = std::max_element(begin, end);

    if(maxit != end) {
        std::cout << *maxit << '\n';
    }
}
```